# PHP exec() will not execute

Tags: php, python, exec, nltk, wordnet

I am writing a php file that will take in a word, and then display the synonyms of that word using Wordnet. I am calling a Python script using

```
exec("python script.py word", $output, $val);
```

Except, the return value is 1, meaning did not find. The file is in the same folder, I can even run it in the terminal just fine, albeit give it a few seconds.

Here is the Python script:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import sys

arg = sys.argv[1]

def synset(word):
   synonyms, synAll, synAllSplit = ([] for i in range(3))
   for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets(word)):
      word = " ".join(j.lemma_names())
      synonyms.append(word)

   for word in synonyms:
      synAll.append(str(word))

   for word in synAll:
      split = word.split()
      for s in split:
         synAllSplit.append(s)

   return synAllSplit


synonyms = synset(arg)
print synonyms
```

Comment: Nothing to do with permissions?

Comment: I don't think so. I previously used the exec()  for another python script and works fine. Just not with the wordnet one.

Comment: Not sure what your problem may be but running this seems extremely inefficient. Every time you run the script you have to reload the wn wrappers. I had a similar project and what I do is I have a webservice serving the python code using simplehttpserver and I did cURL requests from PHP. It's simpler than it sounds.